# C++/SDL render text

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a little application which uses SDL_ttf to display text. This works just fine via: `TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "text here", textColor );` However, I was wondering how I would go about rendering integers. I am assuming they would need to be casted to strings first, but I am running into a problem with this. Specifically when I want to display the x and y position of the mouse like such:

```
if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION )
{           
    mouse_move = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "need mouse x and y here", textColor );
}
```

I believe I can grab the x and y coordinates via `event.motion.x` and `event.motion.y`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::stringstream tmp;
tmp << "X: " << event.motion.x << " Y: " << event.motion.y;
mouse_move = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, tmp.str().c_str(), textColor );
```

Comment: They just seem to show ups as dots: `... ..`. Do you know why?

Comment: Its set to 14. All the text before it is fine. I see `mouse coords: ... ...`

Comment: Could it be that your font doesn't have glyphs for numbers in it?

Comment: Did you call SDL_QueryTexture to get the right W & H for your render rectangle? (ex: SDL_QueryTexture(Tex, NULL, NULL, &rect.w, &rect.h);)

Answer (score 3):

> I am assuming they would need to be casted to strings first

Nope, not casted but converted. The simplest way is using streams, something like:

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

std::stringstream text;
// format
text << "mouse coords: " << event.motion.x << " " << event.motion.y;
// and display
TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text.c_str(), textColor);
```

Comment: What is weird is they just show up ass dots `.. ...` when displayed

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use something like `boost::lexical_cast` or `boost::format`

```
int r = 5;
std::string r_str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(r);

int x = 10, 7 = 4;
std::string f_str = boost::str( boost::format("Need %1% and %2% here") % x % y );
```

I tend to avoid `std::stringstream` unless its iterative.  You have to check `.good()` or the like to see if it failed, and it's not as common as you'd hope.